# How to enforce NOT NULL for sixth normal form in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, normalization, constraint

I have a table `person` which I am planing to normalize to the sixth normal form.
The table has attributes `username`, `email`, and `phone`. The reason I want to go to the sixth normal form is keeping the change history of these columns and adding additional metadata to them (e.g. the confidence level about the data).

I am planning to create new tables `person_username`, `person_email`, `person_phone` and have the `person` view which brings them all together and has `INSTEAD OF` triggers so that users can insert and update the view and these changes get directed to the underlying tables.

My question is, how to enforce `NOT NULL` constraints when using the sixth normal form. How to assure that there definitely is a row in `person_email` for each `person`?

Comment: Why do you need this strange split to add metadata? Can't you add the metadata to the original `person` table? What about pointing the foreign keys in the other direction?